Need Google Script for Nseindia.com API JSON to Google Sheet
I trying to get NSE active contract API data to Google Sheet but I am unable to get data to Google Sheet with Google App Script unable to get data using fetchurl; anyone have any idea to pull data from NSE site into Google Sheet or Excel sheet?
function myfetchapigooglense()
{
Var url='http://www.nseindia.com';
Headerr={};
Var dataT=Urlfetchapp.fetch(url,Heaterr);
Logger.log(dataT.getContentText());
}


What does this have to do with Excel (one of your tags)?
